# Laravel: One to Many relationship, pull last N record from table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a User model and workLOG model. The user model has many work logs, meaning One user can have many work logs (ONE TO MANY RELATIONSHIP). I have created a relationship using the Eloquent relationship.

**User Model**

```
public function workLog()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\WorkLog','user_id','id');
}
```

**workLog Model**

```
class WorkLog extends Model
{
    protected $table="worklog";
}
```

The worklog table has a column called `total_hours_per_day`. How can I pull the last N records from the column of the logged-in or authenticated user?

What I have done to get workLog so far

```
$worklogs = Auth::user()->workLog;
```

Now I want to get last 7 data from the column `total_hours_per_day`

**Screenshots of the table**
[image]

[image]

Comment: what do u means last 7 datas  from the column total_hours_per_day, do u mean the 7 max total_hours_per_day rows?

Comment: @TsaiKoga to pull the last 7 data of one user see eg user_id 14 can have multiple records. How can I pull last 7 data of that user

Comment: @TsaiKoga did you get?

Comment: if the count of these multiple records exceed 7, you need to get the latest 7 datas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$worklogs = Auth::user()->workLog->take(-7)->reverse();
```

and I pull the last 7 records from `total_hours_per_day`column in the blade template as:-

```
@foreach ($worklogs as $worklog)
{{ $worklog->total_hours_per_day }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to establish on the `WorkLog` model a `belongsTo`.

```
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Edit: relationships have to be established in both models you're trying to relate. If you like a girl, she needs to like you back to establish a relationship. You just defined the relationship in one side.

Answer (score 2):

Try using  [take()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-take) 
As Laravel documentation says:
"The take method returns a new collection with the specified number of items"